# SharpDevelop hotkey to show override list of a method?

Tags: methods, overriding, hotkeys, sharpdevelop

Why typing `(` after a method name, a list of override methods will be showed. But after that, e.g. while we are in the between of the two parentheses, we can't call that list to show back.

I'm looking for way/hotkey to show the list - i.e. similarly in Visual Studio, we use `Ctrl - Shift - Space`. What is it in SharpDevelop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no shortcut specifically for re-opening that list.

However, it will be automatically re-opened when pressing comma in an argument list.